# Can I draw circles, ellipses or square in XAML in a Xamarin Project?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, geometry, figure

Good, I want to draw circles, squares, ellipses and triangles in a Xamarin project but I can not find how, in UWP it can be done like this:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Ellipse Fill="Yellow"
              Height="100"
              Width="200"
              StrokeThickness="2"
              Stroke="Black"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the question is that I do not know if I need a NuGet package or some complement for it in Xamarin

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw circle (only achieved by code), you could refer to the following code.

```
public class SimpleCirclePage : ContentPage
{
    public SimpleCirclePage()
    {


        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(),
            StrokeWidth = 10
        };
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 3, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);

    }
}
```

Details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/circle

If you want to use XAML and code to draw Ellipse,you could refer to the following code.

In XAML

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:skia="clr- namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
         x:Class="SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Basics.EllipseFillPage"
         Title="Ellipse Fill">

<skia:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
```

code

```
public partial class EllipseFillPage : ContentPage
{
    public EllipseFillPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        float strokeWidth = 5;
        float xRadius = (info.Width - strokeWidth) / 3;
        float yRadius = (info.Height - strokeWidth) / 3;

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Black,
            StrokeWidth = strokeWidth
        };
        canvas.DrawOval(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, xRadius, yRadius, paint);
    }
}
```

If you want to draw sharps ways that only use XAML (like in UWP), you could download [this plugin](https://github.com/stormlion227/ShapeControl.Forms) .